# How to determine if std::filesystem::remove_all failed?

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to use the non-throwing version of [`std::filesystem::remove_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove), I have something like:

```cpp
bool foo()
{
  std::error_code ec;
  std::filesystem::remove_all(myfolder, ec);

  if (ec.value())
  {
    // failed to remove, return
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to use `error_code`?

My reasoning:

I read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove):

> The overload taking a std::error_code& parameter sets it to the OS API
> error code if an OS API call fails, and executes ec.clear()

Now [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code):

> clear - sets the error_code to value 0 in system_category

Now I used this to imply `error_code == 0 => No error. error_code != 0 => error`.

I really can't any much examples of uses of `error_code`. I just want to determine if all the files have been removed or not.

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct. Just make it fail by e.g. write-protecting the directory to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works on Windows, I just don't know what "sets the error_code to value 0 in **system_category**" really mean, or how portable this is (I don't have access to a linux box to try this out). I'll do some digging, thank you!

Comment: note that `foo` is missing a return in the successful case

Comment: `and executes ec.clear()` if no error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `ec.value()` and `ec != std::error_code{}`; in the case where the error code in `ec` is a different error category than system error and has a value of `0`, the first will return false, while the second will return true.

Error codes are a *tuple* of categories and value.  Looking only at the value is a tiny bit of "code smell".

In this case, I don't think it is possible for the error code to have anything except the system category.  And it would be bad form for a non-system error category to use the value 0 for an actual error.

If there was no error (value 0) with a non-system error code, treating it like an error is probably a bad idea.  So maybe you shouldn't be checking the category.

Finally, `if (ec.value())` is a verbose way of saying `if (ec)`.  I'd use the `explicit operator bool() const` instead of calling `.value()`.

Another option is:

```
if (-1 == std::filesystem::remove_all(myfolder, ec)) {
  // failed to remove, return
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.